# Is my vacuum breaker working properly?

Tags: plumbing, backflow-preventer

I am in a newly rented house around 1 week and I don't know a thing about plumbing (not yet and I love projects for DIY).

So my question is regarding this: [image][image]  I find this attached to the outdoor pipe where I connect my hose. I bought a water gun hose attachment; when I connect it to the pipe and "turn it on", water starts to come from the small holes on the vacuum breaker. Is it normal? Or do I have to fix it myself or contact my landlord!

Comment: Rent.  Love DIY.  You realize those things are not compatible, right?   This is a "check with your landlord" mainly so you can get him to pay for it lol!v

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Harper I can ask to the landlord to fix it. But I dont know if it is broken or not that ia the reason I am asking. If the repaird is more than $100 my landlord will fix it

Comment: Just remove it and hook your hose straight to the hose bibb. If it works fine then you are good.